# How to filter a dataframe and get a sub data frame based on frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame. Lets call it df. My data frame has a column with categorical values e.g. a column named Place. But the problem is that there are many different (string) values in that column and many of them are really rare. Thus, I want to delete these categorical data with low frequency so that I could use dummies. How should I delete those with low- frequency or equivalently, only keep most frequent ones, maybe using a threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a percentage threshold = (frequence /total rows of the dataframe)> threshold. You can choose threshold according to your dataset. Here, I have chosen 10% i.e. 0.1

```
df['Place'].value_counts()/df.shape[0]
```

```
Canada    0.304348
Egypt     0.304348
US        0.260870
UK        0.086957
Mexico    0.043478
Name: Place, dtype: float64
```

Filtering out the rows i.e. threshold>0.1 (10%)

```
sd=df['Place'].value_counts()/df.shape[0]>0.1
sd = sd[sd != False]
list1=sd.index.to_list()
```

Dropping the rows less than the threshold

```
df=df[df['Place'].apply(lambda x: x in list1)].reset_index()
df['Place'].value_counts()
```

```
Canada    7
Egypt     7
US        6
Name: Place, dtype: int64
```